# Chrome doesn't delete "session" cookies

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

I have a problem with Chrome web browser.

When I make a cookie with PHP and expiration time is 0, so it should be deleted after browser is closed. But it didn't. It's still there. When I go to Privacy -> Content settings -> All cookies and I find my cookie, there is

> Expires:  When the browsing session ends

But after restart Chrome, cookie is still there. Cookies, where is some expiration date, are deleted correctly.

Should I report it? By the way, I tested it in Opera and there it works fine, after restart it isn't there

**Edit:** My version is: 27.0.1453.110 and I have Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: OK, I can see that this problem is across versions, so I report a bug...

Comment: close this question too!

Comment: How can I do this? I can't find it in help or somewhere here.

Comment: I thought the option would be available to the OP. Never mind.

Comment: I flagged it, so maybe

Comment: unflag it buddy. This question doesn't pose any serious problem. LOL

Comment: I flag that this is duplicated and posted your link